# AWS Step/Lambda - storing variable between runs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my first foray into any computing in the cloud, I was able to follow Mark West's [instructions](https://github.com/markwest1972/smart-security-camera) on how to use AWS Rekognition to process images from a security camera that are dumped into an S3 bucket and provide a notification if a person was detected. His code was setup for the Raspberry Pi camera but I was able to adapt it to my IP camera by having it FTP the triggered images to my Synology NAS and use CloudSync to mirror it to the S3 bucket. A step function calls Lambda functions per the below figure and I get an email within 15 seconds with a list of labels detected and the image attached.

[image: Step functions]

The problem is the camera will upload one image per second as long the condition is triggered and if there is a lot of activity in front of the camera, I can quickly rack up a few hundred emails.

I'd like to insert a function between make-alert-decision and nodemailer-send-notification that would check to see if an email notification was sent within the last minute and if not, proceed to nodemailer-send-notification right away and if so, store the list of labels, and path to the attachment in an array and then send a single email with all of the attachments once 60 seconds had passed.

I know I have to store the data externally and came across [this article](https://sc5.io/posts/amazon-aws-lambda-data-caching-solutions-compared/) explaining the benefits of different methods of caching data and I also thought that I could examine the timestamps of the files uploaded to S3 to compare the time elapsed between the two most recent uploaded files to decide whether to proceed or batch the file for later.

Being completely new to AWS, I am looking for advice on which method makes the most sense from a complexity and cost perspective.  I can live with the lag involved in any of methods discussed in the article, just don't know how to proceed as I've never used or even heard of any of the services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SQS queue`](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) to which the lambda `make-alert-decision` sends message with each label and path to attachment.

The lambda `nodemailer-send-notification` would be a consumer of that queue, but being [executed on a regular schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

You can specify that lambda to be executed every 1 minute, reading all the messages from the queue - and deleting them from the queue right away or setting a visibility time suitable and deleting afterwards - to get the list of attachments and send a single email. We would have a single email with all the attachments every 60 seconds.

Comment: Would that just slow the rate of messages? I am trying to reduce the total volume of messages without losing any.

Comment: Sorry @MattD. I misunderstood your question at first. I just edited my answer with a different suggestion, still using SQS queue, but also lambda with regular schedule to read from that queue. It might work for you :)

Comment: That sounds promising! I skimmed through the documentation and while it is pretty far over my head, hopefully I can [find](https://gist.github.com/understeer/91753c60adc17e791ec1) [enough](https://cloudonaut.io/integrate-sqs-and-lambda-serverless-architecture-for-asynchronous-workloads/) [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html) to cobble something together.  How could I ensure the first message in a sequence is processed right away and the rest go into the queue?

Comment: Maybe FIFO SQS Queues (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) can help with this